# node js / express get posted data

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, express

How do I get posted data from my api. I am using express `3.4.4`

I am doing a resful api to accept posted data using node js and express

```
exports.mypost = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.username);
    console.log(req.body.name);
    var user = new UserInfo({name:"dsd", username:"dsdsds"})
    user.save();
    res.send("user created");
}
```

and I post data use

```
 curl --data "username=dsds&name=dsd" http://localhost:3000/mypost
```

I can see prints

```
{ username: 'dsds', name: 'dsd' }
dsds
dsd
```

But If I use

```
 curl --form "username=dsds&name=dsd" http://localhost:3000/mypost
```

I see

```
{}
undefined
undefined
```

which means I didn't catch username and name from

```
req.body
```

How do I get the data from

```
 curl --form "username=dsds&name=dsd" http://localhost:3000/mypost
```

I am posting my app.js:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var user = require('./routes/user');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/data');
// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);


var api = require('./controllers/api.js');
app.post('/mypost', api.mypost);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
App.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Make sure its set before all your routes.

Comment: I added this line. Still not working `undefined
undefined
undefined
`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bodyParser method to get the data from a post request

```
// Configure server
app.configure(function() {
app.use(express.bodyParser());
}
```